# how to insert json data into Neo4j in Linux

Tags: linux, neo4j

I am trying to insert a json file into Neo4j in Linux. 
Using Python i can already load the file but i want to store it in Neo4j.
My code is like this:

```
import json
from py2neo import Graph

graph = Graph()

with open ("yelp_academic_dataset_business.json") as data_file:
     json = [json.loads(line) for line in data_file]
query = """
RETURN {json}
"""
print graph.cypher.execute(query, json = json)
```

Can someone help?

Comment: Have you also considered [`apoc.load.json`](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#load-json)?

Comment: To store this in Neo4j, You need to decide the data model. You need to create Nodes/Relationships using the data in json. Have you decided how you want to map this with Nodes/Relationships?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at dict2graph (disclaimer: i wrote this module :) )

https://dzd-ev.github.io/dict2graph-docs/

`pip install dict2graph`

```py
import json
from py2neo import Graph
from dict2graph import Dict2graph

graph = Graph()

with open ("yelp_academic_dataset_business.json") as data_file:
     json = json.loads(data_file.read()
Dict2graph().parse(json).create(graph)
```